# C++ Overloading with default parameters

Tags: c++, function, overloading

i have a little question, how can i initialize default arguments in an function?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;
    float area(float a, float b, float c);
    float area(float a, float b=a, float c =a);


    int main() {

        cout << area(10) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

float area(float a, float b, float c){
    return a*b*c
    }
```

i am getting errors, how can i impelent correctly?

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting. And also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers.  
Finally, [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/) is a great place to start learning C++.

Comment: Note that only error here is that your are using local variable `a` as default parameter. Since multiple declarations are allowed, if you replace `a` by something that can be evaluated when function is called everything will work fine, but you will have only 1 function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to use overloading instead of default parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
float area(float a, float b, float c);
float area(float a);

int main() {

    cout << area(10) << endl;
    return 0;
}

float area(float a, float b, float c){
  return a*b*c;
}
float area(float a){
  return area(a,a,a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want default value for `b` and `c` to be the value of `a` then you should use overloading:

```
float area(float a, float b, float c){
   return a*b*c
}
float area(float a) {
   return area(a, a, a);
}
```

C++ does not allow to use parameters as default arguments. So this

```
float area(float a, float b=a, float c =a);
                           ^^          ^^
```

is an Error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++

you should prototype and implement the code for only one method including the optional parameters and the default values is the optional parameter is ommitted **must be a constant** and not an unknown value...

```
    float area(float a, float b=0, float c=0);
    int main() {
        cout << area(10) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

float area(float a, float b=-1, float c =-1);){
    if(b==-1 ||c==-1)
    {
        return a*a*a;
    }else
    {
        return a*b*c;
    }
}
```